# React MUI: How to create a flex-box like grid using the Grid component

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am using React and MUI as the UI library for my application. I have a big list of elements that I want to order in a specific way. Using the **Grid** component would normally solve the problem.

```
 <Grid container
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="start"
                alignItems="center"
                spacing={4}
                className={classes.Grid}
            >
                {Cards.map(c => (
                    <Grid item xs key={c._id} >
                        <Card id={c._id} title={c.title} description={c.description} />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
</Grid>
```

Styles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    Grid: {
        margin: "auto!important",
        width: "90vw!important",
    }
});
```

Every single element in the grid has a specific **height and width**. Using the code, **this is what the result looks like**:

```
 _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _
|     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     |
|_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _|

         _ _ _           _ _ _          _ _ _  
        |     |         |     |        |     | 
        |     |         |     |        |     | 
        |_ _ _|         |_ _ _|        |_ _ _|
```

Also the spacing between each item does not remain static. It is manipulated by the screen size.
A wider screen will result into a bigger gap between each element.
**What I really do want**:

```
 _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _
|     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     |
|_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _|

 _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   
|     | |     | |     | 
|     | |     | |     | 
|_ _ _| |_ _ _| |_ _ _|
```

This is where I got using **css flex-box**:

```
<Box
        sx={{
               display: "flex",
               justifyContent: "center" ,
               gap: "20px",
               flexWrap: "wrap",
               margin: "auto",
               width: "90vw",
           }}
       >
                {Cards.map(c => (
     <Card key={c._id} id={c._id} title={c.title} description={c.description}/>
                ))}
</Box>
```

If the screen size is too small, the last element on the row will be wraped on the next row. But there is only one problem, the columns on the last row are **centered**, but I just want them to be positioned at the **start of the row**, with the same gap size.
*So how can I really achieve something similar to what I want?*

Comment: You should use grid not flexbox for two dimensional layouts.

Comment: I used css grid but decided to try the Grid component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
display: "grid",
gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, 220px)", //the width of the card 
justifyContent: "center",
gridGap: "20px",
```

**Body**

```
<Box className={classes.List}> //css
    {Cards.map(c => (
        <Grid item xs key={c._id} >
            <Card id={c._id} title={c.title} description={c.description} />
        </Grid>
    ))}
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to use grid, give appropriate value in the breakpoint `sx`, `md`, etc. Also, you don't need to pass the props: `direction`, `justifyContent` and `alignItems` to the `Grid container`

```
<Grid item xs={3} md={3} key={c._id}>
...
</Grid>
```

example:

```
<Grid container spacing={4}>
   {Cards.map((c) => (
     <Grid item xs={3} md={4} key={c._id}>
         ...
     </Grid>
   ))}
</Grid>
```

---

2. For FlexBox:
   just remove `justifyContent='center'` props.

Comment: 1. The gap between each item does not remain static. It is still manipulated by the screen size. (ex: a preset 4px gap should remain 4px no matter how large the width of the screen is. Also each element on the same row overlaps another when the screen size is too small. They should be wrapped on the next row. 2. I just want each row to have the columns postioned in the center, but the last row should have something similar to grid's last row where the first colum is positioned on the same vertical axis position and the rest just goes by simetrically